# 1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module:

Tags: arch-linux, php, mariadb, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin on my Arch Linux box. I then created a sym link named `phpmyadmin` in my `/usr/share/nginx/html/` to `/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/`. When I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/` in my browser I get **500 Internal server error**. Checking in my nginx error log this' what I find:

```
2017/06/13 19:10:42 [error] 4059#4059: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 121" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Please how do I solve this error? How do I get my phpMyAdmin working?
If you need my nginx.conf or php.ini let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: )` sounds like your PHP is misconfigured (or not configured). What are your session settings in `php.ini`?

Comment: @derobert please have a look at the session block of my php.ini here https://pastebin.com/5V9kWhbf

Comment: Does un-commenting the session.save_path setting help? Weird that the default would be blank, though.

Comment: I uncommented the line and provided a subdirectories integer and a path as directed. like so `session.save_path = "3;/tmp"` and restarted nginx. I still get the same error in the nginx error log.

Comment: ☹ Not sure what's going on then. I suggest [edit]ing your question to include those details, and hopefully someone with more knowledge of PHP on Arch will take a look.